# Add deletion policies to specific sites or adding specific sites to deletion policies

Tags: sharepoint-online, compliance-center

In the compliance center you can add specific sites to a deletion policy. What we need to do is make sure specific sites will delete all documents not modified 3 years. But as we have 16000 sites we need to automate it. Is there any API for doing this?

Answer (score 0):

You could create a retention policy to delete all documents not modified 3 years in specific  sites.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I know :D But we have over 20000 sites and need to add around 16000 sites. And every time a new site is created we will add based on a condition. For a big enterprise customer it not an option to do it through the UI. That is why I am asking for an API approach to do exactly what your are showing so we can automate the process.

Comment: Doing what your showing would properly take us years to do and we would have to do a lot of this on a daily basis. Manual work is not an option when your a large customer.

Comment: As far as I know, there is no such API.  Or  you could use some custom codes to delete documents not modified 3 years.